# Check DB Null in table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I get data from a table but the 'DateOfBirth' field is shown as `null`.
So if 'DateOfBirth' is `null` how can I skip it?

> EXCEPTION : Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type

```
var dd = dx.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => new StaffModel
{
    userno = x.Field<string>("USERNO"),
    dateofbirth = x.Field<DateTime>("DATEOFBIRTH"), // This comes as a DB NULL.
    passportno = x.Field<String>("PASSPORTNO"),
    passportexp = x.Field<DateTime>("EXPDATE")
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check for DBNull value in this way:

```
var dd = dx.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => new StaffModel
{
    userno = x.Field<string>("USERNO"),
    dateofbirth = x["DATEOFBIRTH"] != DBNull.Value ? x.Field<DateTime>("DATEOFBIRTH") : DateTime.MinValue,
    passportno = x.Field<String>("PASSPORTNO"),
    passportexp = x.Field<DateTime>("EXPDATE")
});
```

If value is equal to `DBNull.Value` then set `MinValue` or whatever you want.

Comment: DateTime.MinValue;

Comment: Fix my fault. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a nullable `DateTime`; `DateTime?`. In your `StaffModel`:

```
public class StaffModel
{
    public string userno { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dateofbirth { get; set; }
    public string passportno { get; set; }
    public DateTime passportexp { get; set; }
}
```

Then when filling that model:

```
var dd = dx.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => new StaffModel
{
    userno = x.Field<string>("USERNO"),
    dateofbirth = x.Field<DateTime?>("DATEOFBIRTH"), // note the ?        
    passportno = x.Field<String>("PASSPORTNO"),
    passportexp = x.Field<DateTime>("EXPDATE")
});
```

Comment: Date of birth is not a nullable type.in my database there's a issue, for the time being i need to skip it

Comment: `Date of birth is not a nullable type` Your exception would appear to say otherwise.

Comment: actually DB coming from outside,it's a DB issue... for the time being i need to skip that..

Comment: Either way the solution is the same. You cannot supply `null` to a `DateTime` - only `DateTime?`. If you want to skip working with that value you would need to add some logic to the code which deals with your resulting `IEnumerable<StaffModel>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `DateTime.MinDate` if your variable is not null type.

```
var dd = dx.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => new StaffModel
{
    userno = x.Field<string>("USERNO"),
    dateofbirth = x.Field<DateTime>("DATEOFBIRTH") ?? DateTime.MinDate, 
    passportno = x.Field<String>("PASSPORTNO"),
    passportexp = x.Field<DateTime>("EXPDATE")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for DBNull.Value

```
object value = x.Field("DATEOFBIRTH");
if (value == DBNull.Value)
{
    // do something
}  
else
{
    // do something else
}
```